# Screensharing tool for Offline Network

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm working an a network without internet connection. What options do I have for a screen sharing tool?

Comment: With your rep you should know what is [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some sort of connection to the network locally due to not having an internet connection. from there on you can use VNC or Microsoft RDP in order to remotely access the screen.

If your the administrator of this 'offline' network, then you will need a router and a switch in order to locally address the machines via IP or Netbios Name.